# Why Intel's SNB and IVB gives us a opportunity to scaling frequencies?

Tags: linux, cpu, frequency

I mean currently Linux governors, like ondemand and performance, only use several frequencies. What is the purpose of this technique, enabling 16 frequencies to scale, for users? Mapping a program to a certain frequency is non-trivial.